# How to gracefully restart CBCentralManager, in Swift

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbcentralmanager

How do I gracefully stop all CBCentralManager activity and then, later, restart it?

He's my plan.  Is anything missing?

Stopping...
If inadvertently still scanning, then stop.
Unsubscribe all services and characs.

Restarting...
scan
connect
add services and characs.